# Having problems in uploading icon in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to upload an icon and figured out that it requires .ico file, so I converted it again, but it's not uploading.

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Tic tac toe Game")

# Inserting icon to my tic tac toe game

root.iconbitmap('img.ico')

root.mainloop()
```

Please help me from this issue.

This was the Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "img.ico" not defined
```

Comment: does it throw any error??

Comment: Any errors shown in console?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could let us know the error you are receiving. Copy pasting the relevant error in verbose form is also a good idea generally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An icon file isn't necessarily required, there's a way to use something other than an ico if you wanted that luxury:

```
from tkinter import PhotoImage
image = PhotoImage(file="favicon-32x32.png")
root.iconphoto(False, image)
```